# Increase font-weight bold thickness

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm using Wordpress with a custom genesis theme (and Bootstrap) with Google fonts (Open Sans).

Within the styling of my H2 tag I've added: font-weight: bold; however I'd like to increase the thickness of the bold whenever I use the font-weight: bold tag.

URL: https://www.moneynest.co.uk/how-to-budget/

Example H2 text (How to Budget - Table of contents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use font-weight: 800 or font-weight: 900 which are the only values bolder then font-weight: bold

Comment: Thanks but if I do this nothing changes?

Comment: I guess you should use a font family that accepts such values. If a font family doesn't have these options for font-weight then I am not sure If you can use it.

Comment: Or, simply use a font that is blacker. The Google Fonts page allows you to select fonts with a thickness of your choosing.

Comment: I use Open-Sans which has thicker varieties, if I change the font-family to: open-sans:800 it shows as thicker so I know it can work, it just don't know how to make it thicker on bold.

Comment: I think something else might be making it thinner - maybe bootstrap?

Comment: CSS `font-weight:bold` sets the font weight to 700, so if you start out with a 800 weight, `bold` makes it lighter.

Comment: On the website that you provided you have this css rule:
h1.title{font-weight: 300;}
which comes from 
https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/A.style.css,qver=2.2.4.pagespeed.cf.BhBBYYpoKs.css

Maybe this creates the conflict and you are not able to make the font bolder.

Comment: @vadber Nice find, but the OP's question is about the H2, which has a computed style of 700.

Comment: Try to check if the imported Open Sans font in the <head> tags has options for font-weight: 800 or 900, also try to clear your cache and test in more browsers. 
You can try to import the font like this:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 8):

You can use multiple text-shadows to make text bolder even if the font doesn't support the higher font-weights:

```
h2.section {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px, 1px 0px, 1px 1px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, nice idea.